# Debugger seems to be unable to connect to Android FM Application

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

Yesterday I installed Delphi XE7 with Mobile Add On Pack. Unformtunately I'm unable to debug an application running on the attached android device (Galaxy S5 / Asus Tablet).

After experimenting for several hours I can report the following (based on a newly created app):

The source code gets compiled, the application starts up (showing the splash screen) and then Shows the MainForm (The app seems to run properly). The Delphi compile Window stays open (forever, I suppose). Cancelling the compile window shows the "gdbserver" start error. Using another debugport results in following:

The source code gets compiled, the app starts an then shows a black screen. The Delphi compile window closes and Delphi stays in dev mode (means the START/DEBUG button stays enabled the STOP is disabled).

I've worked since severall weeks with XE6. At the beginning I faced similar Problems, I solved by using another debugport or using "adb kill-server" followed by "abd usb". An application created with XE6 ran properly until Installation of XE7 and shows now similar Problems (using XE6).

The device is properly connected. "adb reboot" restarts the device. SDK Manager Settings seem to be correct. Using Windows 7 64 bit (Ultimate).

Since several months I have Problems with the length of my PATH Variable, so I stripped it down by deleting unused entries. Maybe the problem is there.

Has anyone experienced similar behavior?

Any Help is apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have your Project file or units on a network-share, please move it to a local folder.
2. If you have installed IDEFixPack, please uninstall it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try and follow docwiki guide:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Installing_the_USB_Driver_for_Your_Android_Device

You may also need to update your device software for Windows in "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Devices and Printers".

Comment: I updated the SDK as suggested an also checked the device software. Same behaviour.